# HTML-Email responsiveness - images "blocks"

Tags: email, responsive-design, html-email

Currently working on the first serious responsive html email and got totally mad that - sometimes - the email is fully responsive but other times it is just exceeding it preset boundaries within the table-td construction.
I've limited it down to the images, mainly the head image. Once the email is sent, it exceeds the borders and ruins the email. This, while all other images proceeds as normally.
But this would only be solved by hard work, however as I said it is - sometimes - fully responsive, i.e. the head image as well.

To get it to be responsive as intended, using mac and apple mail, I open the .html document in browser and presses cmd+I; this before all the images have loaded. Basically just showing border, background color and text. If the cmd+I command would be to slow, i.e. even one image loaded, the responsiveness gets wacky again.

Fun fact (not so much): if done properly, i.e. fast as described, the Apple Mail client doesn't show the "attachment" paperclip in inbox but does in preview, large window.

Providing html as well as  css for the first three (and 3 biggest) images as well for generic for this area. Why would the header image act this way? Understood the guide as the width="100%" would override the set width.

Basically followed guide from [tutsplus.com](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919) with simple modifications (bg-color, border, sizes etc)

```css
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.webkit {
  max-width: 602px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.outer {
  Margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 602px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.full-width-image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

.inner {
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  Margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #ee6a56;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.webversion {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  Margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
}

.headline {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}

.one-column .contents {
  text-align: left;
}

.one-column .p {
  font-size: 14px;
  Margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .two-column .column,
  .three-column .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .two-column img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .three-column img {
    max-width: 50% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-windth: 401px) and (max-width: 620px) {
  .three-column .column {
    max-width: 33% !important;
  }
  .two-column column {
    max-width: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="margin-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important;margin-left:0 !important;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;background-color:#f9f9f9;">
  <center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#f9f9f9;">
    <div class="webkit" style="max-width:602px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:30px;">
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="602" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                        <![endif]-->
      <table class="outer" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:602px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#d3d3d3;background-color:#ffffff;">
        <tr>
          <td class="webversion" style="padding-right:0;padding-left:0;background-color:#d3d3d3;text-align:center;font-size:10px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;">
            <a href="BROWSER LINK" style="color:#ee6a56;text-decoration:underline;">READ IN BROWSER</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="full-width-image" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
            <img src="IMGLINK/huvud.png" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:600px;height:auto;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="one-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
            <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
              <tr>
                <td class="inner contents" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;width:100%;text-align:left;">
                  <p class="h1" style="Margin:0;font-size:21px;font-weight:bold;Margin-bottom:18px;text-align:center;">HEADLINE HERE</p>
                  <p class="p" style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;Margin-bottom:10px;">TEXT GOES HERE</p>
                  <p class="p" style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;Margin-bottom:10px;">TEXT GOES HERE</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="two-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                                                <![endif]-->
            <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
              <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                <tr>
                  <td class="inner" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                    <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:left;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                          <img src="IMGLINK/utb.png" width="280" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:280px;height:auto;" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">TEXT GOES HERE
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                                                <![endif]-->
            <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
              <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                <tr>
                  <td class="inner" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                    <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:left;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                          <img src="IMGLINK/erf.png" width="280" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:280px;height:auto;" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;"> Text goes here
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <![endif]-->
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: do you inline it prior to sending? Also which email clients are giving you issues?

Comment: Yes everything is inline as by in. This css is directly from the <style>.
The once Im able to try for now are gmail web client, outlook windows10 client, outlook web client, iPhone stock as well as apple mail. The unpredictability comes with the images; if cmd+I before = client present the email suitably. Gmail web stays intact so acceptable; outlook webb, the same; outlook client as the predecessors; apple mail is perfect; iPhone stock as well.
However, if done after img load: half img width in gmail & outlook, apple mail exceeds borders, iPhone shows none scaled (as every width maxed)

Comment: Somethings to note: outlook does not read width in styles, which means if your images are wider than 600px it will break your template. You need meta tags for iOS so it displays properly on the devices. The tut at tutsplus.com is using the method called hybrid email which doesnt reply on media query (media queries are used to beautify). Your HTML has a lot of padding on TD's (and other things) which are not necessary and will bloat the size of the email.